# Android Thread and UI

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

Because if I start an activity, and I launch the threads in the method onResume, the UI of Activity is displayed only when the thread ends?

```
@Override

protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    processDocuments();

}


private void processDocuments(){
  parser = new Parser(rssDocument.getDocument(),rssDocument.getFeedRSS(), listener);
  Thread processThread = new Thread(parser);
  processThread.start();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Show some code that replicates this rather odd behavior.

Comment: Are you downloading on the UI thread there, in getFeedRSS() or in the Parser() constructor? Move that stuff to the background thread. And use an AsyncTask, not a Thread.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're doing a whole lot of stuff to get the parser up and running.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to run the thread in the background using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
private class getRSSS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(void... args) {
    parser = new Parser(rssDocument.getDocument(),rssDocument.getFeedRSS(), listener);
    Thread processThread = new Thread(parser);
    processThread.start();

}
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Set a toast to say finished. You are allowed to update the UI here.
    }
```

}